# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJS and I keep getting Uncaught TypeError.
Basically, when I try to send the message an encrypt it, that is when I end up getting the error.

The error I am getting is within the cryptoJS package. Line 256 starts at 
`var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);`

I am assuming the issue is within the piece of code I have listed below, or there it is when I have been importing the package.

[image]

```
    var myString = messageInput.value;
    var myPassword = 11111;
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);
```

Comment: This code is not runnable as-is and you don't explain where you're getting the error.  How exactly do you expect to get help with this?  Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: try `var myPassword = "11111";`

Comment: Your plain text must be a `string`, not `number`.

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you it worked! I changed it to a string and its good to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer written from comments in OP.

Password be a string not a number. Rather than entering "11111" to test try "testpassword".